# How to implement mutiple-user based cdh hadoop env?

Tags: security, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

we've built hadoop cluster based on cdh, and now would like to implement mutiple-user to protect data for each user, is there andy good solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Hadoop comes with Linux type permissions. One user cannot access another user data, unless he is superuser.

Apart from that, You can consider using Hadoop ACL's and Sentry